# PySide Error emitting dataChanged signal in QAbstractItemModel subclass

Tags: macos, qt, pyside, qmodelindex

I'm getting this error when trying to emit `dataChanged` signal:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
TypeError: Value types used on meta functions (including signals) need to be registered on meta type: QModelIndex
```

Here is the relevant part of my `QAbstractItemModel` subclass:

```
class PropertyItemModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PropertyItemModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item = self.getItem(index)
        result = item.setData(index.column(), value)

        if result:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

            # Doesn't work either (same error):
            # self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)"), index, index)
            # QtCore.QObject.emit(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("dataChanged(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)"), index, index)

        return result
```

I'm using PySide version 1.2.1 with Qt 4.8.5 on Mac OS X (10.10). 
The error can be related with my specific environment. This code was working on another mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this was caused by installation conflicts. I've had different flavours of python (system, brew, package from official site).

Fresh install using homebrew fixed the problem.